# Surge deployment Yeoman Angular needs individual js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman-generator-angular, surge.sh

I am attempting to do a quick and dirty deployment of my app on Surge, and I am running into an issue with Yeoman Angular.

Basically, it's asking for references to the individual files for my directives, while the scripts are all combined into 1 file.

Is there a way I could include all the individual JavaScript files? Or does anyone know what I need to do with my deployment build so it renders properly on Surge?

Comment: are running surge through dist? are you using grunt or gulp?

Comment: This was using Grunt through Yeoman-angular. And I was running through dist -- I ended up sort of giving up on this angle and just did it properly through Digital Ocean.

Comment: why don't you use Heroku? checkout this guide on using Heroku: https://github.com/aniknafs/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/docs/generators/heroku.md